# ajax.microsoft.com vs cookieless domain for cdn

Tags: http, cdn

If I'm right, each request for http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.js 
uses something like 3kb of microsoft.com cookies. Do I not understand something and it doesn't matter or is Microsoft wrong?

Comment: Uhh is there a question that you were asking or what?

Comment: Can you please clarify that last sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because there's a whole bunch of cookies set for the microsoft.com domain, which will naturally also be sent to requests to its subdomains as well. Microsoft is doing it wrong.

Google, on the other hand, uses a separate domain (googleapis.com) for its CDN, for which at least I have exactly zero cookies. I suggest you use Google's CDN instead.

Comment: I'm not sure why anybody would use Microsoft's CDN over Google's

Comment: I use if for the jQuery Validation plugin. As far as I know, Google do not host a copy.

Comment: http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.min.js (if anyone wants the link)

Comment: The darn ajax validation link seems down right now, and its breaking my page. thanks microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You are right and Microsoft solved this eventually by creating **ajax.aspnetcdn.com**:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#ajaxmicrosoftcom_renamed_to_ajaxaspnetcdncom_15

> ajax.microsoft.com renamed to ajax.aspnetcdn.com
>
> The CDN used to use the microsoft.com domain name and has been changed
>   to use the aspnetcdn.com domain name. This change was made to increase
>   performance because when a browser referenced the microsoft.com domain
>   it would send any cookies from that domain across the wire with each
>   request. By renaming to a domain name other than microsoft.com
>   performance can be increased by as much to 25%. Note
>   ajax.microsoft.com will continue to function but ajax.aspnetcdn.com is
>   recommended.
>
> Old Format: http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.0.js New
>   Format: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.0.js